# how to convert current code to Item.restrict in redemption

Tags: c#, outlook-redemption

I am checking duplicate item before copy to folder. I checked first folder. If not exist,Created then and then checking items duplicate using redemption.

My code is

```
childParent.Items.OfType<RDOMail>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Subject != null && x.Subject == mailItem.Subject && x.SenderEmailAddress == mailItem.SenderEmailAddress && x.ReceivedTime == mailItem.ReceivedTime);
```

This code take too much time if I have many items in side folder

I tried to convert above code to

```
childPrent.Items.Restrict(filter);
```

but it is not working.

```
 string filter=$"[Subject]='hello test' AND [ReceivedTime]='2020-05-07 05:07:22' AND [SenderEmailAddress]='user@ashyam.com';
```

it is not working if i put ReceivedTime equal date.

I am using redemption and C# programing

Thanks
Shyam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not use [] - Redemption use SQL syntax, [] are for OOM.
Secondly, never use `=` with DateTime properties: the condition will never be satified due to round-off errors even if you do specify the milliseconds (which you don't). Always use a range:

```
 string filter=$"(Subject='hello test') AND (ReceivedTime > '2020-05-07 05:07:21') AND  (ReceivedTime < '2020-05-07 05:07:23') AND (SenderEmailAddress='user@ashyam.com');
```

Comment: Is there way to include  reply forward (fw:,re:) text in filter?

Comment: Search on `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F`) instead:  string `filter=$"(\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F\"='hello test') AND (ReceivedTime > '2020-05-07 05:07:21') AND  (ReceivedTime < '2020-05-07 05:07:23') AND (SenderEmailAddress='user@ashyam.com');`

Answer (score 0):

Outlook evaluates date-time values according to the time format, short date format, and long date format settings in the Regional and Language Options applet in the Windows Control Panel. In particular, Outlook evaluates time according to that specified time format without seconds. **If you specify seconds in the date-time comparison string, the filter will not operate as expected.** You need to exclude seconds from the filter.

Another aspect - it is recommended to compare the date interval, not direct point of time.

But I'd recommend comparing the `PR_SEARCH_KEY` property value instead. This property provides a trace for related objects, such as message copies, and facilitates finding unwanted occurrences, such as duplicate recipients.

MAPI uses specific rules for constructing search keys for message recipients. The search key is formed by concatenating the address type (in uppercase characters), the colon character ':', the email address in canonical form, and the terminating null character. Canonical form here means that case-sensitive addresses appear in the correct case, and addresses that are not case-sensitive are converted to uppercase. This is important in preserving correlations among messages.

Comment: I got value of PR_SEARCH_KEY  from current item but it is in binray format . how to pass it in  folder.items.Restricted(<here>) ?